# js path changes after publishing mvc application

Tags: javascript, path, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on mvc5 web application and I put all my .js files in Script folder. 
However, I added ckeditor plugin and I put all files regarding ckeditor in new folder named "ckeditor" and it's on the same level as default "Script" folder.

I added ckeditor.js in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ckeditor").Include(
                   "~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"));
```

and added it to _Layout.cshtml

Internally ckeditor depends on config.js and some other files in "ckedit" folder and everything works fine on local server.

The problem is when I publish application. I got errors like:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

path: http:site.com/ControllerName/config.js?t=E3OD
```

And everything regarding ckeditor is trying to load from this path.

Why is it trying to load config.js from this path and only when I publish the application.

What do I have to do to make it work locally and on production.

Comment: I guess http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath and  http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration will be helpful.

Comment: I changed basepath like CKEDITOR.basePath = '../ckeditor/' and everything works noe. Thank you